# Multiprocessing in python on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

Any basic information would be greatly appreciated.

I am almost completed with my project, all I have to do now is run my code to get my data. However, it takes a very long time, and it has been suggested that I make my code (python) available to multiprocess. However, I am clueless on how to do this and have had a lot of trouble running how. I use a Mac OS X 10.8.2. I know that I need a semaphore.

I have looked up the multiprocessing module and the Thread module, although I could not understand most of this. Do the Process() or Manager() functions have anything to do with this?

Lastly, I have 16 processors available for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the multiprocessing module.

Both modules enable concurrency, but only multiprocessing enables true parallelism. Due to Python's Global Interpreter Lock, multiple threads cannot execute simultaneously.

Keeping all 16 of your processors busy comes at the cost of a certain increased difficulty in programming since separate processes do not execute in a shared memory space, so if a spawned process needs to share data with its parent process you will need to serialize it.